# Power cut out while running floor maintainer - breaker blown?

Tags: electrical

I was running a floor maintainer in my home yesterday, and after a few minutes the power to that circuit just stopped. I went and flipped the breaker a couple times, but no changes. I noticed that the circuit I was using was (for whatever reason) ran as a 15amp - I assume this is why it tripped.

I'm pretty clueless on electrical work here - what would be my next step to figure out how extensive the problem is?

More worrisome is that it appears that one of the bedroom's circuits is now no longer working as well. I'm not 100% sure it occurred at the same time, but that's my assumption for now. I don't understand why this would happen though, because the two rooms are on opposite ends of the home. I wouldn't think they'd put both on the same circuit?

Answer (score 2):

When you reset the breaker were you sure to first go to the off and than on position?
When a breaker trips it goes into the trip position which is centre on the handle. But to reset it, you need to go to move the handle to the off position and than the opposite way to the ON position. Sometimes people forget to go off first and just try to go from tripped to ON which will not work.

Comment: Hm, maybe it didn't trip then... it was still in the `ON` position when I checked.

Comment: Don't let that fool you. Sometimes they look on yet they are tripped. Just switch all the way off and than on. But it's not necessarily your problem, I just wanted to add that.

Comment: So now you would need to see if there was voltage coming out of that plug. You could get a multimeter or just do a quick check with a lamp that works in another plug. Does it work in this one?

Comment: I know for sure none of the outlets on that circuit work atm - I flipped the breaker a couple times, and even flipped the main breaker to the house. No dice

Comment: I would start at the panel than. Making sure that when the breaker is on, you have 120v coming from the screw on the breaker to the neutral or ground bar,